# How to execute maven plugin before resources are filtered when using war packaging

Tags: maven, maven-3

**Summary**

The first phase for `<packaging>war</packaging>` in the [Default Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings) is for `process-resources` which immediately calls the `maven-resources-plugin`.

How can I execute a plugin before that runs?

I was hoping there is an easy way to change the ordering when running `process-resources` to let the another plugin run first.

Or perhaps force one of the earlier phases to be included in the lifecycle, 
 without going as far as [Creating a custom lifecycle](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingACustomLifecycleInMaven?_sscc=t)

(I'm actually surprised that `war` packaging doesn't use `validation` or `initialization` since they seem to make sense for any type of build)

**Detail**

I'm trying to use the `buildnumber-maven-plugin` to generate generate the `${buildNumber}` and use filtering to save it in the *.properties file which usually runs as part of the validate or initialize phase. So I tried to bind it to the `process-resources` phase for execution since it was the first.

The problem is that `maven-resources-plugin` is the very first thing to execute before the `buildnumber-maven-plugin` has a chance to generate `${buildNumber}`.  All other properties are filtered fine.  (I'm aware I can probably do something in a later step with  `maven-war-plugin` using the `web.xml`, or in the manifest, but that's not what I'm asking)

If they can't be reordered within process-resources, I was hoping I could force the `initialization` phase to be included in the lifecycle with some kind of easy configuration in the existing `pom.xml`

Perhaps something that looks like the `components.xml` when defining the custom lifecycle.

```
<configuration>
            <phases>
              <initialization>org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:create</initialization>
            </phases>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The war packaging doesn't bind any plugin goals to the validation or initialization phases by default.  Those phases are still available, and you are free to bind plugin goals to either phase in your project's POM.  If the buildnumber plugin must run during the `process-resources` phase then Jaffar's solution is correct.

Comment: I understand that packaging doesn't itself bind plug-ins.  But the war packaging doesn't **use** validation or initalization phases, so any plug-in bound to them are not executed like they would be with the default lifecycle. That's why I asked if there was a way to force the 'initilaztion' phase anyway, without having to define a custom lifecycle that adds it and re-defines war packaging.  If I'm missing something else from your response, please let me know.

Comment: I would need to see your POM.  I have goals bound to both validation and initialization and they are executed correctly.  (The default lifecycle is the default lifecycle, it is the same no matter which packaging type is used.  What goals are bound to the lifecycle change the processing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If maven plug-ins are bound with same phase, then they executes in order of their listings within pom
`maven-resources-plugin` is by default bounded to `process-resources` but it is declared in super pom and when you build, super pom, parent poms and current pom make up a single pom known as effective pom ( *you can check your effective pom via* `mvn help:effective-pom`)

Now coming towards the solution, to change the order of execution of plugins.

1. First add `buildnumber-maven-plugin` and bind it to `process-resources`
2. Beneath `buildnumber-maven-plugin` add `maven-resources-plugin` and bind it to process-resources

Now when you build both will be executed during `process_resources` phase but `buildnumber-maven-plugin` will be executed before `maven-resources-plugin`.

Comment: Sneaky, but that worked. Note: It is actually resulting in calling the resources plug-in twice. However I can live with that. (Since it is quick, and calling it twice doesn't cause any other side-effects that I"m aware of)

Comment: Set the execution ID for the resources plugin: `<id>default-resources</id>` and that will remove the additional execution.

Answer (score 0):

ok,I solved this right now, thanks for @Jaffar Ramay's answer and their comments.

we can invoke the `maven-resources-plugin` again after the `buildnumber-maven-plugin` created buildNumber. But Jaffar Ramay's answer don't work for me, `maven-resources-plugin` to compile and set the execution id as default-resources, try to remove the additional execution.

here is my pom.xml  hope it could help someone.

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>/conf</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                            <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                            <useLastCommittedRevision>true</useLastCommittedRevision>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-resources</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

See Maven lifecycles: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html
Lifecycle Reference chapter. There are several phases before process-resources one, for example generate-resources, that you can use to bind your plugin configuration, so it will be executed before `<resources>` part of the build.

Comment: please post a full answer, and the links for more information.