# Bind Maven resource filtering to specific phase

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, m2eclipse

I am on Eclipse 2019-09 and trying the following:

I created a file `src/main/resources/build/build.properties` to hold some information about the current build:

```
build.version=${project.version}
build.number=${buildNumber}
build.date=${buildTimestamp}
```

When building the project the variables get replaced correctly and the file inside the target folder is rendered correctly. When changing code in Eclipse (without a Maven build), the `buildNumber` gets replaced by its variable name.
I suppose it has something to do with m2e doing the filtering too often (not only when clicking *build* via the menu). The `buildNumber` is only available during the "real" build and so it is not available on other occasions, hence it is not getting replaced.
Can I tell Maven to only execute the variable replacement during a specific build phase?

Relevant excerpt from the `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>123</groupId>
    <artifactId>456</artifactId>
    <version>789</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <buildTimestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</buildTimestamp>
    </properties>
    <!-- Dummy for Build Number Plugin -->
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://127.0.0.1/dummy</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://127.0.0.1/dummy</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1/dummy</url>
    </scm>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${buildNumber}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <!--  Maven Build Number Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>buildnumber</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <format>{0,number}</format>
                    <items>
                        <item>buildNumber</item>
                    </items>
                    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                    <revisionOnScmFailure>unknownbuild</revisionOnScmFailure>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Working example showing my problems:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.whatever</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.5.0</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <buildTimestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</buildTimestamp>
    </properties>
    <!-- Dummy for Build Number Plugin -->
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://127.0.0.1/dummy</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://127.0.0.1/dummy</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1/dummy</url>
    </scm>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${buildNumber}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Copy dependencies into target/lib -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Create JAR -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.whatever.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--  Maven Build Number Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>buildnumber</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <format>{0,number}</format>
                    <items>
                        <item>buildNumber</item>
                    </items>
                    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                    <revisionOnScmFailure>unknownbuild</revisionOnScmFailure>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Create a simple class org.whatever.test.Main.java with just a sysout:

```
package org.whatever.test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Hey!");
    }
}
```

And create a `build.properties` under `src/main/resources`:

```
build.version=${project.version}
build.number=${buildNumber}
build.date=${buildTimestamp}
```

Building increases the build number by three. Changing your Main.java (causing recompilation) makes the replaced version of the `build.properties` in the target directory lose the build number.

**EDIT:** Fixed the by-three-incrementation. Thanks to khmarbaise. Still left with the replacing issue. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html states

> Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: process-resources.

which comes just before compile. Eclipse probably does a `compile` on every code change (just guessing) and replaces the resources. On this phase no buildNumber is available (and I do not want to increase this number on every code change). I cannot find out how to bind to another phase or go a more elegant way.

**EDIT:** The more I am thinking about it the more I am thinking of keeping it this way. Building via Maven increments my build number. The build process also zips my class files, libraries etc. Inside the target directory and in the zip files, now there is the correct build number. Changing my code results in the build number being reset to ${buildNumber} in target/classes which is technically correct. I am not on the same build as I was before changing the code, I am somewhere between builds.

Comment: You have bound the buildnumber-maven-plugin to `clean` phase.. ? Just remove the phase in your configuration cause the plugin knows where to bind in the life cycle...

Comment: Thanks, first I chose another phase which did not work, then I tried `clean` (not the best, I know...). I thought the phase had to be provided. But this does not fix my problem with not wanting Maven to replace variables in my project when not explicitly building. One single change in the code starts the variable replacing process again and my build number inside the target directory becomes ${buildNumber}. The other variables (especially `build.date`) are still the ones from the last explicit build and do not get refreshed.

Comment: Ah, I remember why I used `clean` there. Not providing a phase increases my build number by 3 and not by 1. My Maven goals are `clean validate compile package assembly:single verify`. Apart from my dependencies the only other plugins I use are `maven-assembly-plugin` (jar-with-dependencies) and `maven-dependency-plugin` (to copy libraries into a folder inside `target`).

Comment: I have just added a c&p example.

Comment: If you are using this `clean validate compile package assembly:single verify` than you misunderstood the lifecycle...If you use assembly plugin it should be bound to the life cycle (`package`) and that should result in simply calling `mvn clean package` or `mvn clean verify` nothing else.. Each call `package` contains `validate` and `compile` so you are repeating several parts of your build...

Comment: Yeah, still learning. I thought the lifecycle goals could explicitly be stated. This works now as expected, thank you. Still having the variable problem, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think the build of Eclipse won't bother Maven's building.

The truely problem is the `maven-resources-plugin` invoked in 'process-resources' phase,and your `buildnumber-maven-plugin` runs after that.

Here is my solution here, hope it works for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70604055/13049551